# Is there a way to remove specific strings from indexes using a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remake the built-in function for bin(x) for better understanding, I have got that part down, now the issue is how to dynamically remove the 0s when they are not necessary.

I have tried using replace() but it seems to be removing every suggested "0"  I am unsure how to select the zeroes till it hits the first index in which there is a "1"
for eg:

```
if i have 0b00010010
            ___
          0b00010010
               ^
```

I would like to select the numbers after the 0b and erase the 0s right after until "1"

```
def bin(x):
    if x>0:
        binary = ""
        i = 0
        while x>0 and i<=16:
            string = str(int(x%2))
            binary = binary+string
            x/=2
            i = i+1
            d = binary[::-1]
            ret = f"0b{d}"
        return ret.replace("00","")
    else:
        x = abs(x)
        binary = ""
        i = 0
        while x > 0 and i <=16:
            string = str(int(x % 2))
            binary = binary + string
            x /= 2
            i = i + 1
            nd = binary[::-1]
            ret = f"-0b{nd}"
        return ret.replace("00","")

print(bin(8314))# 0b00010000001111010 this is the current out
```

0b00010000001111010 this is the current output

0b10000001111010 this is what I want

Comment: Can't you just keep replacing `0b0` with `0b` until there aren't any more to be replaced?  Or replace a regex like `0b[0]*` with `0b`?

Comment: unfortunately, I am relatively an amateur at this, I am still understanding the loop concepts but I will try this method and see if it's more simple to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better to simplify things by not generating those extra zeroes in the first place:

```py
def bin(x):
    prefix = ("-" if x < 0 else "")
    x = abs(x)
    bits = []
    while x:
        x, bit = divmod(x, 2)  # division and remainder in one operation
        bits.append(str(bit))
    # Flip the bits so the LSB is on the right, then join as string
    bit_string = ''.join(bits[::-1])
    # Form the final string
    return f"{prefix}0b{bit_string}"

print(bin(8314))
```

prints

```
0b10000001111010
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [`lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

```
>>> b = "00010000001111010"
>>> b.lstrip("0")
'10000001111010'
```

Of course, make sure to prefix the binary with `"0b"` **after** calling `lstrip()`.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hunter brought up a nice solution to your problem, however, if you want to use a for loop, consider trying the following:

```
binary = "0b00010000001111010"
start_index = binary.find("b")
for index in range(b+1, len(binary)):
    if binary[index] == 0:
        binary = binary[0:index:] + binary[index+1::]
    else:
        break
```